# Solve the Diophantine equations: $|a^2 -2b^2|=1$?

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $a$ and $b$ such that:
$$|a^2 -2b^2|=1$$
The solutions to this equation are related to the units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: You are right. Note that $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit if and only if $a^2-2b^2=\pm1$.

Comment: This equation can be solved using the convergents of $\sqrt{2}$ , the $+1$-case is the well known Pell-equation, the $-1$-case an also well known variant.